# Помогите решить задачу на яндекс контест

Tags: python

При планировании межпланетной миссии в марсоход «зашили» ежедневные планы работ — списки задач на каждый день. Но в реальности оказалось, что планы слишком объёмны: марсоход не успевает выполнить за день все запланированные задачи.

В Центре управления марсоходами решили сократить ежедневный объём работ. Для этого марсоход ежедневно должен удалять из своего дневного расписания одну задачу. Какую именно задачу удалить — определяют в ЦУМе. Договориться толком руководители Центра не смогли и каждый день бросают жребий, случайным образом выбирая задачу для удаления. Индекс удаляемого задания передаётся марсоходу.

Технические условия задания
Перечень заданий хранится в связном списке.

Для выполнения задания используйте прекод.

Напишите функцию solution(), которая принимает на вход голову связного списка и индекс элемента. Функция должна удалить из списка элемент с указанным индексом и вернуть голову обновлённого списка.

В этой задаче не нужно считывать входные данные.

Отправка на проверку
При отправке решения на проверку должен быть выбран компилятор Make.
Решение нужно отправить в файле (не через форму), это строгое условие.
Файл должен быть с расширением .py и не должен называться solution.py.
При нарушении этих условий даже корректно написанное решение не пройдёт тесты.

Как проверить свою работу перед отправкой
Для запуска тестов просто запустите скрипт через терминал. Например, так: python my_best_solution.py. Если не появилось никаких ошибок — всё в порядке, можно отправлять файл на проверку.

Прекод

```
# Импорт модуля os из стандартной библиотеки 
# для взаимодействия с операционной системой.
import os
# Считывание переменной окружения REMOTE_JUDGE, чтобы определить, 
# локально выполняется код или на удалённом сервере.
LOCAL = os.environ.get('REMOTE_JUDGE', 'false') != 'true'

# Если код выполняется на локальном компьютере, то...
if LOCAL:
    # Класс, описывающий элементы связного списка:
    class Node:
        def __init__(self, value, next_item=None):
            self.value = value
            self.next_item = next_item


def solution(node, idx):
    curent_node = node
    while idx != 0:
        idx -= 1
        curent_node = curent_node.next_item
    return node


# Тестирующая функция для проверки решения.
# Не изменяйте её, она не требует вашего внимания.
def test():
    node3 = Node("Задача 4: Обследовать грунт в радиусе 3 м", None)
    node2 = Node("Задача 3: Измерить температуру атмосферы", node3)
    node1 = Node("Задача 2: Пробурить скважину глубиной 0.5 м", node2)
    node0 = Node("Задача 1: Фотосъёмка 360°", node1)

    new_head = solution(node0, 1)
    assert new_head is node0
    assert new_head.next_item is node2
    assert new_head.next_item.next_item is node3
    assert new_head.next_item.next_item.next_item is None
    # result is node0 -> node2 -> node3


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Функция должна вернуть голову связного списка, в котором удалён нужный элемент.

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу.

Comment: ``` def solution(node, idx):  
    curent_node = node
    while idx != 0:
        idx -= 1
        curent_node = curent_node.next_item

    return node ```

Comment: Выдает ошибку и все, мыслей как решить вообще нет

Comment: Если выдает ошибку - добавьте текст ошибки в вопрос.

Comment: Нарисуйте связный список на бумаге и распишите, как удалять первый элемент, и не первый

Answer (score 0):

```py
def solution(node, idx):
    if idx == 0:
        return node.next_item

    current = node
    for _ in range(idx - 1):
        if current.next_item is None:
            return node  # Если индекс больше длины списка, возвращаем исходный список
        current = current.next_item

    # Удаляем следующий узел
    if current.next_item is not None:
        current.next_item = current.next_item.next_item

    return node
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]